# How to resize UIImageView in UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I want to display image in cell, and because I need to download it first so I would like to display (for question simplicity) black view with the same width and height like image should be displayed.

Because I want to stretch image to same width as cell width, I only need aspect ratio for setting height and this is provided in my code when `cellForRowAt` is called.

I decided to achieve "black view" before downloading image I only need one UIImageView with black background, and resizing it when `cellForRowAt` is called. But here is the problem, because using code from similiar questions is not working for me.

I tried something like this in `cellForRowAt` method:

```
var frame cell.imageView.frame
frame.size.height = CGFloat(aspectRatio) * frame.size.width
cell.imageView.frame = frame
```

**EDIT**

As a result I want something like facebook, where we have photo with the same width as cell and height accordingly to aspect ratio. For simplicity cell can only have UIImageView.

Comment: Are you using autolayout?

Comment: Yes, I'm using autolayout

Comment: So why are you doing this programmatically?

Comment: But how can I set specific aspect ratio of UIImageView if there is now image inside, only black background?

Comment: You can set uiimageview background color to black and when you get image change its background color to clear color and set your downloaded image

Comment: Probably we don't understand each other, can you explain how would you do that using autolayout?

Comment: would be better you provide screen shot of your actual requirement which you want to design.

Comment: You can set aspect ratio of UI image view in storyboard. Select imageview and drag its control to same imageview and then select aspect ration.

Comment: But how can I set aspect ratio if I only know about aspect ratio in cellForRowAt method?

Comment: [self.yourview addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint
                                  constraintWithItem:self.yourview
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                  toItem:self.yourview
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                  multiplier:(self.yourview.frame.size.height / self.yourview.frame.size.width)
                                  constant:0]];

Comment: Would be better if you expain it with your expectation screen shot. Lke what is currently happining and what you want exactly

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using auto layout, in the storyboard you should set two things:

- First, set the width of the `UIImageView` to be the full width of the cell
- Second, set the *aspect ratio* of the `UIImageView` to 1:1 - this says the height is always the same as the width.

If you're using the `UITableView`'s *Automatic Dimensions* for cell heights, this should be all you need; no code anywhere, everything else is as normal.

If you're not using the automatic cell height feature, then either set the cell height once with `self.tableView.rowHeight = self.tableView.bounds.size.width` if they're all the same, or, if the cells can be different heights:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat { 

    if (<indexPath IS IMAGE ROW>) 
        return tableView.bounds.size.width
    return <default height>
}
```

Where I've written `<indexPath IS IMAGE ROW>`, you should replace that with whatever condition you need to detect if this particular cell is an image type.
Also, as Rikh pointed out, where I've written `<default height>`, you should replace that with the height of the cells that are *not* the image type.
Of course, you may have a much more complex design for your table; this just covers the case you were asking about.

Comment: Thanks for the formatting edit, Rikh: I was typing in a rush :-)

Comment: No issues! But i think you ought to have a look at your `heightForRow`, there should be a default return type if the code doesn't enter the `if` condition :)

Comment: FYI I'm using Automatic Dimensions ;)

Comment: But with your solution assuming that I'm using Automatic Dimensions I will always have square image which is not what I wanted in question.

Comment: Ahh, ok - your original question sounded like you wanted the same width as height.

Comment: The thing about auto layout is that when you modify a frame directly, you will break the auto part - you should create a layout constraint for the height, set it as an outlet into the cell's class, and set it directly that way.
You may need to call `cell.setNeedsLayout()` after that, although I've found many bugs and deficiencies this way - auto layout tended not to work for me.

Answer (score -1):

here my solution

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
if (imageView.bounds.size.width > ((UIImage*)imagesArray[i]).size.width && imageView.bounds.size.height > ((UIImage*)imagesArray[i]).size.height) {
       imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit;
}
```

Comment: The question is tagged "swift", not "objective-c". Please always respect the question's tags. You should post the Swift version instead.